# How to remove the element from list if its key is duplicated but value must be appended to single key in java?

Tags: java

I have list ,

But , what i want to do is ,
In the  list ,key  is duplicated, so i have to remove that record but the value should be appended to single key

My approach:

```
ArrayList<Students> students = new ArrayList<Students>();
student = getDetails();
    for(int i=0;i<students.size();i++)
     {
       for(int j=i+1;j<students.size();j++)
        {
           if(students.get(i).getName().equals(students.get(j).getName()))
             {
                string name=students.get(j).getName();
                students.set(i).setName(students.get(i).getName()+","+name"");
                students.remove(j);
             }
        }
     }
```

here in this i am only able to append the index 1 value to index 0..The loop is getting out for next iteration.

```
Input:
Name=Student1   Id=1000, 
Name=Student1   Id=1003, 
Name=Student1   Id=1004,


Expected output:
Name=Student1   Id=1000, 1003,1004

Actual getting output:
Name=student1 Id=1000,1003
Name=student1 Id=1004
```

Comment: You're removing from the list while iterating over it. That's a no-no.

Comment: Then final output should be filtered right. Then can i have a soolution please

Comment: I came here to get a solution. For my expected output i thought its a solution.But i dont find solution anywhere to get m expected output.

Comment: I'l append the value to first but at last i'l get appended value with all other values right

Comment: If you want to put a band-aid on your code that needs stitches, then decrement  `j` after removing. As in add `j--;` after `students.remove(j);`.

Comment: no.. if(students.get(i).getName().equals(students.get(i).getName())) is false, the names are not same, so we ignore that record.

Comment: Sorry.. While writing its a mistake.. So sorry.. Yea 
students.get(i).getName().equals(students.get(j).getName()) is right..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in your question does not produce the output you say you are getting, the following code produces the expected output.

```
class Foo {

    public static void main (String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception
    {
        ArrayList<Student> students = new ArrayList<Student>();
        // student = getDetails();

        // I don't have your database so I added the students manually
        students.add(new Student("Student1", "1000"));
        students.add(new Student("Student1", "1002"));
        students.add(new Student("Student1", "1003"));

        for(int i = 0; i < students.size(); i++) {
            for(int j= i+1; j < students.size(); j++) {
                if(students.get(i).getName().equals(students.get(j).getName())) {

                    // altered this line to produce expected output
                    String id = students.get(j).getId();

                    // also altered this line to produce expected output
                    students.get(i).setId(students.get(i).getId() + "," + id);

                    students.remove(j);

                    j--; // apply bandaid
                }
            }
        }

        for(Student s : students) {
            System.out.println(s.toString());
        }
    }

    private static class Student {
        private String name;
        private String id;

        public Student(String n, String i) {
            name = n;
            id = i;
        }

        public void setName(String n) {
            name = n;
        }

        public void setId(String i) {
            id = i;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return name + " " + id;
        }
    }

}
```

Output:

```
Student1 1000,1002,1003
```

Comment: Thank You so much.. It worked.. thank you for spending your time.. :)

Comment: @Bhanu Remember that `j--` is only applicable to this situation, you should research the proper way to remove items from a list.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to assign values (`Student`) to keys (`Name`), where there can be several values for a given key. You should use a `Multimap` structure instead of an array (cf. [Oracle documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/interfaces/map.html)).

That can be done automatically using the Java 8 Streams:

```
    Student s1 = new Student("Student1", 1000);
    Student s2 = new Student("Student1", 1003);
    Student s3 = new Student("Student1", 1004);
    List<Student> l = Arrays.asList(s1,s2,s3); 
    Map<String, List<Student>> z = l.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Student::getName));
    System.out.println(z);
```

The output is as expected: 
    {Student1=[Id=1000, Id=1003, Id=1004]}

To have this result, I had to override the `toString()` method of `Student` to print the `Id`. I hope it helps.